# want to print caption from instagram post in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to print hashtag and caption given in a post.hashtag I can print it, but in caption it showing it should be an element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]")).click();
        List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='']"));
        for(int j=0;j<tags.size();j++) {
            System.out.println(tags.get(j).getText());

        }
WebElement caption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/span/text()"));
        String Txt = caption.getText();
        System.out.println(Txt);
```

it print all hashtag but didnt print caption

Comment: What happens if you remove `text()`?

Comment: if i remove text() it showing all the element inside span with comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath locator must be resolved to a [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) i.e. to be a [Node](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes.asp) or a [NodeSet](https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_node_set.cfm) hence your XPath expression cannot return a string, you will need to remove trailing `/text()` bit

Going forward using absolute XPath expressions is an antipattern as they're very fragile and sensitive to markup changes. Consider coming up with a relative XPath query which is stable, easy to read and maintain, in your case it would be something like:

```
//header/descendant::a[contains(@href,'explore')]
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)